# Strange javascript function parameter value

Tags: javascript

I have the following JavaScript function:

```
function changeSelectedCustomerNumber(CustNumber){
    var field = document.getElementById('SelectedNumber');
    field.value = '00'+CustNumber;
}
```

Which is called by pressing the following option:

```
<select style="width:100px;" name="bySubj">
    <option onclick="changeSelectedCustomerNumber(00510443);">blatest</option>
</select>
```

I have several of those checkboxes. what they should do is put the passed number in a separate input field.

My Problem is, that when debugging the JS function, after a click in the option, 
`custnumber` contains `166263`.

I assumed that the cast to num would remove the leading zeros, but how could the parameter be converted like this.

Is there any reason why JavaScript should do something like this?

Comment: `<select>` element is a drop down list (DDL), but not `"button"` or `"checkbox"`.

Comment: 00510443 in Octal is 168227 in decimal, not 166263. I'm guessing you've picked two different examples and conflated them?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that's what I figured too

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your number is being parsed as octal because of the leading zero.

If the leading zeroes are significant, you should pass the variable as a string (i.e. surround it in single quote marks)

Comment: ... or use `.toString(8)`.

Comment: @VisioN that won't help if the numeric literal still has the zeroes in front of it.  He'd have to strip those first.

Comment: it might be useful to provide a snippet of how he would pass and subsequently parse the string as a number using radix 10.

Comment: @Alnitak Why not? It won't let to auto convert from octal to decimal when doing string concatenation with `"00"`, i.e. do `"00" + CustNumber.toString(8)`.

Comment: @jbabey I'd be more concerned with making sure the number was inserted into the source correctly in the first place.

Comment: @VisioN because the conversion from octal to decimal happens _before_ that function has even been called.

Comment: @Alnitak Agree, but anyway both approaches are possible.

Comment: Thanks. I can omit the leading zeros as I will have to append them manually in the js function anyway. Yes, I might have accidentially picked 2 different examples. Thanks for the tip with the octal conversion. didn't think of that. I'll try it out.